# Joining Two Count Queries

Tags: join, count

So this is where I'm at (and this works exactly as needed).  However this is just step one of the project. So the goal is to have this result of this query to display on sheet one via ODBC to excel (never done this so going to have to do a lot of research).  Once displayed in excel user will be able to input date range into...let's say A1 or B1 (not sure yet on design).  So this is really good what I have so far.  So now I am looking to make second sheet with more information then just failed/success.  This second sheet will do exactly what the first sheet does just display more details. THIS WILL ONLY APPLY FOR FAILS.

```
SELECT Sum(case when status = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as Failed,
       Sum(case when status = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as Successful,
   UniqueID
Into #tempsheet1
FROM Documents
WHERE ownerID = 467
and status in (6,9)
and CreationTime between @StartDate and @EndDate
Group By UniqueID

Select D.UniqueID, FromName, ToName, CreationTime,
cast(CreationTime as date) as CreationDate, cast(CreationTime as date) as CreationTime,
ErrorCode, ElapsedSendTime, RemoteID
From #tempsheet1 ts1
Inner Join Documents D On
D.UniqueID = ts1.UniqueID
and [Status] = 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation and sum vs count...

```
SELECT Sum(case when status = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as Failed,
       Sum(case when status = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as Successful,
       cast(CreationTime as date) CreationDate
FROM Documents
WHERE ownerID = 467
  and status in (6,9)
  and CreationDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY cast(CreationTime as date) CreationDate
ORDER BY cast(CreationTime as date) descending
```

Since both queries use documents table and the same ownerID filter, we can just filter for owerID in the where clause. I add status of 6,9 in the where caluse since we could have lots of other status we don't care about and why bother evaluating them?

The sum(case evaluates status and when 6 sets a counter to 1 when failed otherwise it sets the counter to 0) This way the sum of all the 1's and 0's will result in the "count" of failed or successful.

Comment: Actually this is producing incorrect results.  Although the setup is right.  When I run the original code I included without a temp table I get slightly different numbers.

Comment: There is a difference with the sum vs a count.  The count is correct.

Comment: They are both set to integer.

Comment: if integer you shouldn't have the tics around the numbers. Sample data that isn't working would be need.  I can't see why this wouldn't work.  Assuming your goal is to show for client 467 a count of status 6 (failed) and a count of status 9 (successful)

Comment: Using Count:
Failed - 36946 Successful - 3736

Using Sum
Failed - 37032 Successful - 3738

Comment: So if you add the two values do you get this count?

`Select count(*) from Documents where status in (6,9) and OwnerID = 467`  is this "LIVE" data where the values could be changing from moment to moment?

Comment: Sum of failed and successful is 40819.  The query from the last comment is 40825

Comment: Its my fault.  The number is constantly changing.  As faxes come in.

Comment: Live data, can get you every time: P (and I stand behind my original query then)

Comment: You are correct sir.  Your query works perfect.  Live data did get me :( ...However i ran the queries at the same time and your original query added to be the correct sum.  All is good.  Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a creation date parameter to this?

Comment: I don't see why not.  Does the date range vary by status or is it the same data range regardless of status?  (I put -- comments in answer to address options of requirement change  if the same data just put it in the where clause if the date varies by status, then apply it as a compound value on the case statment. :P)

Comment: Requested changes added to my (your) new query in OP.

Comment: What creation time would you want?  Since your summing the values selecting the creation time makes me wonder which time.  Either remove it from the select or better qualify what time you want displayed. (max? Min, Avg?)  You need to think about how the "Creation time" will relate to the SUMMED values of failed/successful.  Do you want the earliest and the most recent? Just the most recent? or do you even need it? can you just filter by it without displaying?

Comment: User input parameter

Comment: User input parameter date range pulled from CreationTime field.  New edit in OP

Comment: If I assume you want the success/failures per day, then I've modified my answer to fit the updated question.  However if you don't want the success/failure by day, then I need to understand what date you want listed.  By casting the datetime to a date we truncate the time portion.  But really if the requirements of the question keep changing, you should post a new question.  You can see over time the original question gets lost and the answer is less valid to the question.  Which is why each question/answer should remain specific to a single topic.

Comment: Thank you so much for the changes.  It won't necessarily be limited per day.    Could be days, weeks years (unlikely).  Just need from StartDate - EndDate.

Comment: So if you don't need the results by day, simply remove the creationdate from the select and group by.  By having the date in the select, you cause the error you initially discussed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.Failed,B.Successful  --before it is '*' which means 'all columns'
FROM 
(
SELECT COUNT([Status]) as Failed, 1 as JoiningValue
    FROM Documents
    Where ownerid = '467'
    and [Status] = '6') as A

INNER JOIN

(
SELECT COUNT([Status]) as Successful, 1 as JoiningValue
    FROM Documents
    Where ownerid = '467'
    and [Status] = '9') as B

ON B.JoiningValue = A.JoiningValue
```

Comment: This is almost what I want.  I am eventually going to setup an ODBC to excel so i need to eliminate the JoiningValue columns from the select statement (I know it's needed to join) but I can't have it in the display.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a creation date parameter to this?

Comment: What do you mean a date parameter? @date? and what is that for?

Comment: I see what you mean in above, you could add `date` or `datetime` range to the end of your query, for example: `WHERE A.datetime` < getdate(), but it depends on the column type and the specific case

Comment: You could just cross join as count w/o a group by will always be 1 record.  So a cross join 1*1 = 1;  No need for JoiningValue.

Comment: Cool, that is a really nice trick way lol good to know that, thx

Answer (score 0):

Just you can `SELECT` this two queries, then you can get that values in one table.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT([Status]) as Failed
into #tempfailed
FROM Documents
Where ownerid = '467'
and [Status] = '6') sa FAILED,
(SELECT COUNT([Status]) as Successful
FROM Documents
Where ownerid = '467'
and [Status] = '9') as Sucess
```